# How to draw a Polyline using a Cartesian array?

Tags: cesium

I need to draw a polyline using the mouse click.

All examples I've found only show the polyline positions using a `Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegreesArray`:

```
var glowingLine = viewer.entities.add({
    name : 'Glowing blue line on the surface',
    polyline : {
        positions : Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegreesArray([-75, 37,
                                                        -125, 37]),
        width : 10,
        material : new Cesium.PolylineGlowMaterialProperty({
            glowPower : 0.2,
            taperPower : 0.5,
            color : Cesium.Color.CORNFLOWERBLUE
        })
    }
});
```

But I need to use a cartesian comming from

```
var cartesian = viewer.camera.pickEllipsoid( movement.position, scene.globe.ellipsoid );
```

This is what I've done but with no success:

```
// Just to illustrate the mouse click consider movement.position different here.

var cartesian1 = viewer.camera.pickEllipsoid( movement.position, scene.globe.ellipsoid );
var cartesian2 = viewer.camera.pickEllipsoid( movement.position, scene.globe.ellipsoid );

    var entity = viewer.entities.add({
        polyline: {
            positions: [cartesian1, cartesian2],
            width : 5,
            material : new Cesium.PolylineOutlineMaterialProperty({
                color : Cesium.Color.ORANGE,
                outlineWidth : 2,
                outlineColor : Cesium.Color.BLACK
            })
        }
    });
```

This don't work. The error is:

```
An error occurred while rendering. Rendering has stopped.
RangeError: invalid array length
m.generateArc@http://localhost:36215/resources/Cesium/Workers/createPolylineGeometry.js:231:7308
m.generateCartesianArc@http://localhost:36215/resources/Cesium/Workers/createPolylineGeometry.js:231:8334
T.createGeometry@http://localhost:36215/resources/Cesium/Workers/createPolylineGeometry.js:231:12962
n@http://localhost:36215/resources/Cesium/Workers/createPolylineGeometry.js:231:14985
o@http://localhost:36215/resources/Cesium/Workers/createGeometry.js:231:22277
i@http://localhost:36215/resources/Cesium/Workers/createGeometry.js:231:21277
a/<@http://localhost:36215/resources/Cesium/Workers/createGeometry.js:231:21418
```

I have a 3D globe with terrain heights.

Comment: Did you found a solution? I cannot draw a polyline using an array of two Cartesian3 but I don't have any errors either (Cesium 1.73). Thanks.

Comment: I can't remember. I think you can first do a `cartesian = ...fromDegrees(longitude, latitude)` for each position and then put them into an array to send to the polyline.positions.